# Create minikube instance on different ip

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-machine, minikube

I've a docker-machine running on my windows, it's ip is `192.168.99.100`. Now I try to install minikube too (different machine).

```
E0723 20:45:33.346900    7192 start.go:300] Error starting cluster:  timed out waiting to elevate kube-system RBAC privileges: creating clusterrolebinding: Post https://192.168.99.100:8443/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1/clusterrolebindings: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

It tries to create it also on `192.168.99.100`. How can I make a minikube instance on a different IP? (I don't want to destroy my docker-machine)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is an issue in Github that talks about minikube sometimes starting on a different ip other than 192.168.99.100: [Minikube starts on different ip]: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/951

> In that same thread there are many folks who have requested for a
>   feature to have a static ip assigned to minikube. Which could mean
>   that we could run minikube on a different ip. There are some workarounds and trials worth trying from the above github issue.